# URL Rewrite to another server

Tags: http, .htaccess, url-rewriting, dns

I have a domaine let's say `http://www.mydomain.com`.
I have some storage on that domain that does not allow PHP, but allows URL rewriting though .htaccess.

I have another "account" on another server that accepts php.
I put the content of my website on it, let's say at `http://myaccess.myprovider.com/mydomain/`

So I have just put a `.htaccess` on the root of mydomain.com to redirect any call from `mydomain.com` to `myaccess.myprovider.com/mydomain`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule www\.mydomain\.com /myaccess.myprovider.com/mydomain [L]
```

But I can't achieve this to work, I get a 403 forbidden error. Probably a problem in the regexp expression. I don't know. Some simplier example works, like the one found [Here](http://www.expreg.com/rewrite.php)

What should I write or do to make this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://myaccess.myprovider.com/mydomain/$1 [P,L]
```

If you want to only send PHP requests there, add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$ [NC]` before the rule.

EDIT: forgot to include the hostname in the condition.

Comment: Starts to work. I go to the dest server, but with a 400 error just typing www.mydomain.com. An index.php exists at dest.

Comment: typing `RewriteRule ^www\.mydomain\.com(.*)$ http://myaccess.myprovider.com/mydomain/$1 [P,L]` gives a 403 error and no server redirection

Comment: The `RewriteRule` directive match does NOT include the hostname. It only matches against the URI with the leading slash stripped off. So going to http://www.mydomain.com/something.php the rule will match against: `something.php`. Check the added condition in my edit

Comment: For SEO purposes, I would recommend [R=301,NC,L] at the end of the rewrite rule.